# subset data frame according to a criteria based on correlation

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame and will like to create a function in which only variables with low correlation are keep. This means looking at the pairwise correlation of each variable with the rest of the variables, and for those variables in which at least one correlation coefficient is greater than 0.4 then this variable and the one highly correlated are taken out from the data frame.

For example suppose I have a data frame:

```
 data <-  data.frame(x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(10), x3=runif(10), x4=runif(10,15,20))
cor(data, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

            x1         x2          x3         x4
x1  1.00000000 -0.3325757  0.08567911  0.2651721
x2 -0.33257569  1.0000000 -0.18761301  0.4660056
x3  0.08567911 -0.1876130  1.00000000 -0.3321003
x4  0.26517210  0.4660056 -0.33210031  1.0000000
```

Then I will like to return a data frame keeping only x1 and x3 (given that x2 and x4 have a correlation of 0.46)

Comment: Did you want to consider negative correlations above a certain strength?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the correlation matrix `cd`, checking if there is anything `>0.4`.
Then subset away, ignoring the `diag`onals, where `row==col`:

```
cd <- abs(cor(data, use="pairwise.complete.obs")) > 0.4
data[-unique(col(cd)[cd & row(cd) != col(cd)])]
```

Comment: OP has accepted your answer but I wonder if negative correlations should also be considered

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
set.seed(50)
data <-  data.frame(x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(10), x3=runif(10), x4=runif(10,15,20))
mycor <- cor(data, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
data[, !apply(mycor, 2, function (x) max(x[-which.max(x)]) >.4 | min(x[which.min(x)]) < -.4) ]
```

Comment: I think you want to subset `data` in the last line, instead of `mycor`

Comment: Right you are - I misunderstood OPs desired output